# RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK is failing

Tags: sql-server-2012, backup, clustering, ola-hallengren

We are having WSFC(Windows Server Failover Cluster) configuration for one of database server and from last few days, backup of one of the database is failing. Sometime backup itself fails whereas on other times restore verify from disk fails.

I am using Ola Hallengren's maintenance script and we have checkdb weekly running for all the database and no issue is reported in that, one time I executed them manually - checkdb as well as backup finished successfully. Did fail-over one time and that day it worked fine however from next day onward its throwing same error. Differential backup just works fine.

Restore verify error is as below:

```
Command: RESTORE VERIFYONLY FROM DISK = N'Drive_name\Server_name\DB_Name\FULL\Server_Name_DB_Name_FULL_20191021_003022.bak' WITH CHECKSUM
Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Server Server_Name, Line 1
Read on "Drive_name\Server_name\DB_Name\FULL\Server_Name_DB_Name_FULL_20191021_003022.bak" failed: 170(The requested resource is in use.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server KHCBSPSQL, Line 1
VERIFY DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Outcome: Failed
Duration: 00:05:13
Date and time: 2019-10-21 00:46:23
```

Backup error is as below:

```
Command: BACKUP DATABASE [DB_Name] TO DISK = N'Drive_name\Server_name\DB_Name\FULL\Server_Name_DB_Name_FULL_20191016_003016.bak' WITH CHECKSUM, COMPRESSION
Msg 3203, Level 16, State 1, Server Server_Name, Line 1
Read on "Drive_Name\MSSQL\DATA\DB_Name.mdf" failed: 170(The requested resource is in use.)
Msg 3202, Level 16, State 1, Server Server_Name, Line 1
Write on "Drive_name\Server_name\DB_Name\FULL\Server_Name_DB_Name_FULL_20191016_003016.bak" failed: 170(The requested resource is in use.)
Msg 3013, Level 16, State 1, Server Server_Name, Line 1
BACKUP DATABASE is terminating abnormally.
Outcome: Failed
Duration: 00:09:19
Date and time: 2019-10-16 00:39:35
```

I am suspecting that these files are used by some anti-virus running on server or some scanner is holding these files however I am not sure why only this specific database is failing. There are more than 20 databases and their backup runs smoothly, also to note that this is the largest one and approximately 100GB. Any help is much appreciated.

Version is as below:

> Server: Windows Server 2012 Standard
>
> SQL Server: Microsoft SQL Server  2012 (SP4-GDR) (KB4057116) -
>   11.0.7462.6 (X64)     Jan  5 2018 22:11:56    Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation     Standard Edition (64-bit) on Windows NT 6.2  (Build
>   9200: ) (Hypervisor)

UPDATE: Copied this backup to test server and restored the same on a new database and restoration completed successfully without any issue.

Executed the backup manually without checksum and backup completed without any error however when it runs with checksum, throws same error as provided above.

Sysadmin has excluded mdf, ldf, ndf and bak type files from live scanning.

Comment: Can you replicate the issue? You could use [sysinternals process explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see what application has an open handle on the file

Comment: @RandiVertongen Thank you for reply. I am not an sysadmin on the server and this is a production server, can run sysinternals only when sysadmins give me permission to do so. I want to rule-out any issue from DB side before going to that step.

Comment: Alright, the commands are failing after 5/9 minutes which seems that something is interupting the backup / restore process. Are you backing up to a disk on the vm itself?  A restore headeronly or a restore filelistonly works right?

Comment: In the normal scenario(when it wasn't failing), restore verify was completing in 7 minutes and backup was completing in 11 mins for this database. I am taking backup at a disk on the vm which is part of cluster and shared disk. I am copying this backup to test now and will see if restoration completes successfully or not.

Comment: Is it a shared disk in a Always On FCI setup? Have you tried backing up to a network share instead?

Comment: It is not part of always on availability group, its windows server fail-over cluster meaning these drives will be detached from this node to another node when fail-over happens. I am not sure if there is any issue in taking backup on that. Later on these backups are copied to tape. We don't have network share as yet for storing backups.